# What is the sense of utilising Local Camera

Tags: camera

I have some misunderstanding about usage Local camera. Referring to the Blender manual it overrides Global (or said differently Scene) camera for the View (I suspect View means View Layer). Okey this option do override Active camera from a Scene camera to any other camera I want to set but I can't set up different Local cameras for different View Layers. If I am changing Local camera for either one View layer this camera at once will be set for all other View Layers, accordingly wait is scene of Local Camera if I can set different cameras for different View layers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local camera is set *per viewport*, not view layer.

Camera view (<kbd>Num 0</kbd>) uses the *Scene camera* by default.
Using Local camera, you can work with more cameras at once.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I thought in the wrong way!