# Making own layout, Toggling through multiple cameras in a scene

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I need to make a layout so I can see individual parts of my scene all at once for editing purposes.

Sort of like my own quad-view; therefore it's not animated and is unlike the solution in  "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one" ).

I could manually move my viewing angle in each viewport into place. However, I discovered the angle in veiwports may all reset when the active camera is changed. So I've placed a new camera objects in the locations I want them (one for editing with, one as the render camera, and one aimed at my custom facial rig and IK/FK UI).

If I add more cameras how can I temporarily toggle through the cameras for quick referance? You know, rotate through the view from each camera but only in one specific "layout window" without changing the active camera in **all** viewports?

*Note: I work in both Blender 2.79 and 2.9 series and would like the answer for both versions please.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the sense of utilising Local Camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185682/what-is-the-sense-of-utilising-local-camera)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Local Camera

Ther's a feature called Local Camera that allows you to specify a camera per viewport.
You can find it in the N bar under view. Just specify the camera for each viewport.

[image]

To enable the feature in 2.79 you must disable the  **lock local camera and layers** toggle in the header (see cursor position below).

[image]

Comment: Great, I knew that at one point but had long since forgotten. Thank you. Since you doe seem to know what you are doing I wonder if you have a solution to the latter half of my question as well. i.e.: Is there a way of rotating through existing camera angles for view purposes only, not resetting the active camera? I was able to do this once using a keyboard shortcut, but can't remember what it was. Thanks

Comment: I usually set up some markers (frame 1, 2, 3....) in the timeline and bound cameras to them, so by simply pressing the left and right arrow keys you can go through each camera. Did you trid that?